# Autocomplete pops up when next input is clicked

Tags: html, css, firefox

**NOTE** This behaviour only occures in FireFox (as least in v66)

I have the following scenario:

- one input type text
- directly below one input type number
- due to pre submittions to the form, the text input provides auto complete values (e.g. Test1 and Test2)
- when I know activate the text input and click on arrow up of the number input, the auto complete values appear and causes the number input to increment the number to its max value

All this can be reproduced here: https://jsfiddle.net/ax7unjhb/2/ (FireFox only!)

Click text input to gain auto complete:
[image]

[image]

Click arrow up; auto complete appears again and overlaps number input:
[image]

Number increased to max value:
[image]

```
<form action="window.location.reload();">
  <input type="text" style="width: 100%;" />
  <input type="number" min="1" max="32" style="width: 100%;" />
  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

**My question**

What causes the auto complete to pop up, although I click another input? This is not the expected behaviour. 
When I click the increase button of the number input, I expect to increase the number by 1.

Comment: Finally got it reproduced… that’s indeed strange. Looks like a Firefox bug.

Comment: That seems to only occur, if the first input has the focus. If you have two text inputs, the one that has the focus is getting 'autocompleted' when the number field is increased or decreased.

Comment: I've made a screencast: http://somup.com/cqfj2rnuUo

Comment: It looks like a FF bug to me too. You should go and file a bug report down at the [FF bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi). You may as well use my screencast and my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f05x96hr/ for that.

Comment: By the way, this is also occuring in the latest Firefox Nightly 68.0a1. Have you reported the bug?

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation, and the screencast. I opened a ticket.(https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1542994)